# How can 1 Corithians 7:14 and Luke 14:27 be reconciled?

Tags: textual-discrepancies, gospel-of-luke, 1-corinthians

> For the unbelieving husband has been sanctified through his wife, and the unbelieving wife has been sanctified through her believing husband. (1 Corinthians 7:14, NIV)
>
> And if you don't carry your own cross and follow me, you cannot be my desciple. (Luke 14:27, NLT).

These two verses seem to contradict each another: The first states you can be sanctified by someone else's belief, but the second says you have to carry your own cross.

How can these two verses be reconciled?

Comment: Please explain the contradiction more. What do you understand 'sanctify' and 'carry your own cross' to mean in these specific contexts?

Answer (score 4):

You missed an essential part of the scripture in 1 Corinthians, I feel. The full scripture in KJV reads:

> 14 For the unbelieving husband is sanctified by the wife, and the
>   unbelieving wife is sanctified by the husband: **else were your children
>   unclean; but now are they holy.**

Paul is opposing views here that may have arisen, that a believing woman should leave her unbelieving husband. In verse 16 I would say it is clear that we are not meant to think the husbands are somehow "auto-saved".

> 16 For what knowest thou, O wife, whether thou shalt save thy
>   husband? or how knowest thou, O man, whether thou shalt save thy wife?

One big subject he is addressing in that letter, and why I highlighted the children part, is circumcision. I feel he is addressing a concern that an unbelieving husband is somehow "unclean" and makes the whole family unclean, or that a husband opposing (or wanting) the circumcision of a son is somehow a problem. I believe the emphasis in verse 14 is on the children, not on the husband.

Comment: Nice phrase: "auto-saved"! Don